# Keep getting NullPointerException when reading file

Tags: java, exception, filereader

This is my method here:

```
private void trackPrinter(){

    File file = new File("track.txt");
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String filePath = absolutePath;

    try {


    FileReader readerT = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader brT = new BufferedReader(readerT);
    jTextArea2.read(brT, null);
    brT.close();
    jTextArea2.requestFocus();
    } catch(Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

I've tried many different ways to pass the file in but each time it throws a NullPointerException. if i use jfilechooser the method works fine, except i want the file to open and read on start up.

Comment: What's the error and possibly because the file doesn't exist?

Comment: Please let us know what line the `NullPointerException` is occurring on.  (And don't just give us the line number--that doesn't help us.  Figure out which Java line it is, and let us know.)

Comment: what is `jTextArea2` ? you should look at that